# How to validate all fields with different aura:Id?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript

I am trying to validate all fields when the user click's on the submit button.

**Issue:** I had to maintain different aura: id's for the lightning input elements, due to some other logic needs to be done on every input.

I would like to know how can I validate all elements on click?

Can someone please advise?

**Component:**

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <lightning:input aura:id="fieldId" label="First name" placeholder="First name" required="true" messageWhenValueMissing="Enter FirstName"/>
        <lightning:input aura:id="fieldId" label="Last name" placeholder="Last name" required="true" messageWhenValueMissing="Enter LastName" />
        <lightning:input aura:id="MiddleName" label="Middle name" placeholder="Middle name" required="true" messageWhenValueMissing="Enter Middle" />
        <lightning:button aura:id="submit" type="submit" label="Submit" onclick="{!c.onClick}" />
</aura:component>
```

**Controller :**

```
({ 
    onClick: function(component, event, helper) {
         console.log("On Click");
       helper.ValidateFirstName(component, event, helper);
       helper.ValidateMiddleName(component, event, helper);
    }
})
```

**Helper :**

```
({
    ValidateFirstName: function(component, event, helper) {
       console.log("On Click helper");
        var allValid = component.find('fieldId').reduce(function (validSoFar, inputCmp) {
            inputCmp.showHelpMessageIfInvalid();
            return validSoFar && !inputCmp.get('v.validity').valueMissing;
        }, true);
   },
    ValidateMiddleName: function(component, event, helper) {
       console.log("On Click Middle Name helper");
        var allValid = component.find('MiddleName').reduce(function (validSoFar, inputCmp) {
            inputCmp.showHelpMessageIfInvalid();
            return validSoFar && !inputCmp.get('v.validity').valueMissing;
        }, true);
   },

})
```

Thanks in Advance !!!!

Comment: instead of having different aura:id's per field name, instead use an aura:id for all fields that need validating and use a name attribute to distinguish the field type or name.

Answer (score 1):

Instad of using the aura:id to perform validations per field type, use a genric aura:id for all your required fields, such as `aura:id='req-fields'` and assigning a representative name attribute for your field types, ex. `name='MiddleName'` this way, you can run your validate method regardless, and instead, check the field name while doing so:

```
Validate: function(component, event, helper) { 
    const fieldName = event.getSource().get("v.name");
    //do your validations based on field name
    ...},

ValidateSubmit: function(component, event, helper) { 
    const allReqFields= component.find('req-fields');
    // do your validations for allReqFields which is an array of all 
    // components with the specified aura:id
    ...},
```

you can invoke your validate method with onchange for `lightning:input`

Comment: Hi glls, thanks for the reply.i cannot use the same aura:Ids for the elements as I have already mentioned in my post. Just trying to find as how can I do the validation on elements that uses different aura:Ids.I will try the above code snippet and check weather it would work for. Thanks

Comment: Glls, I would like all these validations to be happening on the click of the submit button. I didn't clearly understand why the above code snippet has two methods.apologizes  if I got it wrong.

Comment: My only intention, I want this validation is that when the user clicks on the submit button without filling up any field, the fields should have highlighted in red and shows the error.

Comment: it has two methds because in your post you mentioned `Issue: I had to maintain different aura: id's for the lightning input elements, due to some other logic needs to be done on every input.` however, you dont need the first method i posted, only the second one if you want to valdiate on submit

Answer (score -1):

Why would you go for checking all validations using this way. Instead, I would recommend going this way.

Connect Your Lightning input tag with value attribute:

Example :

```
 <aura:attribute name="firstName" type="String" default="" />

 <lightning:input aura:id="fieldId" label="First name" placeholder="First 
       name" required="true" messageWhenValueMissing="Enter FirstName" value = 
       "{!v.firstName}"/>

 <lightning:button aura:id="submit" type="submit" label="Submit" onclick="{!c.ValidateSubmit}" />


  ValidateSubmit :  function(component, event) {

     if(component.get('v.showErrorPrimary') || component.get('v.firstName') || component.get('v.LastNameName') || component.get('v.age'){
       // Your error string.
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
},
```